# Apache Ivy: XML Namespace and Imported Properties

Tags: java, ant, build, ivy

I was looking at an Ant `build.xml` file this morning and noticed an XML namspace delcaration in the root `<project>` element:

```
<project name="${project.name}" xmlns:ivy="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant">
```

I figure this XML namespace is so that all of the Ivy tasks sprinkled throughout the buildscript know which resource to look inside for task definitions (`<ivy:configure>`, `<ivy:resolve>`, etc.), but was hoping for a more thorough explanation of the syntax of this statement.

- What is the concept of a "namespace" in Ant world? Is this `xmlns:ivy=` attribute pointing towards a JAR?
- Where would this `org.apache.ivy.ant` JAR/resources/whatever live?
- What is `antlib` and where is it defined?

Also, just a fleeting thought here, do Ivy files (`ivy.xml`) have the ability to import properties files and use their property values? I looked in the Ivy documentation but couldn't find references to any import-type statements.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The namespace is just like any other namespace as far as XML is concerned. But, Ant is using `antlib:` as a URL scheme to know that it should look for an `org/apache.ivy/antlib.xml` file in the classpath. See the [antlib](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/antlib.html) Type in the Ant manual.

Since it's looking for a classpath, the antlib.xml can be anywhere a classloader can find it. The default setup is to put the necessary jar file in the `<ant install>/lib` directory. You can also start ant with `-lib` to specify a different directory or just set the `CLASSPATH` (not recommended).

Yes, you can can import properties files. See the Ivy manual info on [multi-projects](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/tutorial/multiproject.html). Ivy supports the `${property}` syntax and you can use Ant's `<property>` task to load a file that Ivy can use. You can also use `<property>` elements in ivysettings.xml if you want to define 'global' values for Ivy.

Answer (score 0):

I only have a partial answer for you, and I hope someone can verify it:

- namespace: I'm not sure.  I *think* it's just an XML namespace.
- resources: On the back end, Ant runs a Java program.  The Ant "executable" (really just a .sh script on *NIX and a .bat file on Win) builds it at runtime.
- antlib: is the path to the $ANT_HOME/lib.  It's built at runtime, just like the classpath.
- ivy property files: Yes, you can use properties files (at least with the IvyDE plugin for Eclipse).  I only know this because we have them at work, I don't fully understand the mechanism for how they work.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me to fix the syntax errors in `build.xml` for `<ivy:resolve>`, `<ivy:retrieve>`, etc was to remove the URLs and replace `uri` / `xmlns:ivy`/`xmlns:m` with `"antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant"`.

`build.xml`

```xml
<project name="proj" default="dist" basedir="." xmlns:ivy="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant">
    <taskdef uri="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant" resource="org/apache/ivy/ant/antlib.xml">
        <!-- ... -->
    </taskdef>
    <!-- ... -->
</project>
```

`ivy.xml`

```xml
<ivy-module version="2.0" xmlns:m="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant">
    <info organisation="org" module="proj"/>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- ... -->
    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```